# Process ID files missing from remote Ubuntu Linux PC?

Tags: ubuntu, process, azure, pid, docker

I am running Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS on a PC in my office and on a virtual machine hosted on Azure.  For some reason, the remote PC is not creating a PID file for each process.  Everything else seems to work fine.

For example, given some arbitrary process ID 25512, then on my local box I see this:

```
/proc/25512/ns/pid
```

But on my remote box there is no *pid* file in the *ns* directory:

```
/proc/25512/ns/
```

I need the *pid* file for utilities like *nsenter* so I can enter Docker containers on my remote box while logged in directly to the box, like I can do on my local box.  Why isn't the Azure instance creating the *pid* files while my local box does so successfully?

Note, the remote box appears to work fine in almost every test I run or package I install.  Also, **I *am* using sudo for all the commands I execute in my SSH shell so I don't think it's a user account permissions problem.**  I'm pointing this out because I am aware that the files in this directory are usually owned by the *root* account.

Comment: Are you positive the remote kernel has namespaces enabled?

Comment: @DanielB Is there a command I can run that will tell me if namespaces are enabled or not?

Comment: Apparently, reasonably recent versions of the `ip` can be used: `ip netns` should return a list of namespaces (can be empty).

Comment: @DanielB The command exists but the list is empty as you said it would.  Does this mean I can assume namespaces are enabled?

Comment: Well, at least the net namespace is. If you’re lucky, the kernel config is available at `/proc/config.gz`, which you can then check. Other than that, I’m not intimate enough with the `/proc` internals, sorry